# Why are some option values symbols, other strings?

Tags: options, built-in-symbols, language-design

Is there a rationale, beyond historical accident, why some *Mathematica* option values are strings, while others are symbols?

It seems natural that some value spaces, e.g. named color schemes, are so numerous and only applicable to `ColorData`, e.g. `ColorData["HTML"]` and so should be strings.

On the other hand wouldn't it make more sense if `"XAxis"` in `PairedHistogram[..., BarOrigin -> "XAxis"]` were a built in symbol to be shared as an option value across composite graphics functions?

Comment: Related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167782/using-strings-instead-of-symbols-good-or-evil)

Comment: Btw, strings almost always work even when the option is a symbol

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In older versions (5 and before), most option names were symbols.  It's since about version 6 that string option names have proliferated.

I *think* that the reason is to avoid cluttering the name space.  Once you introduce a new name, it won't be available for package authors to use for other purposes (in particular, function names).  At least not without shadowing the built-in one.  Considering the huge number of options introduced since version 6, I think it was a good decision to use strings for most of them.

Every time a new symbol is introduced in a new version, there's a chance it will break some third party package.  Using strings reduces the likelihood of this happening.  Strings, unlike symbols, are not part of a namespace (so there's no shadowing issue) and can't have associated definitions (so breakage due to conflict is impossible).

Comment: +1. I agree with your reasoning, I also think it is namespace-related. This does however come at a price - string options are much less discoverable in the documentation and otherwise.

Comment: @Leonid Yes, that is the disadvantage.  Auto-completion doesn't work.  Theoretically this could be remedied by improving auto-completion in the front end ...

Comment: Szabolcs' answer makes sense. But also thanks for pointing out documentation - which is often a struggle. One would think keyword registration and search to be entirely feasible.

Comment: Talking about documentation and options, I still couldn't figure out how to use the `"EdgeLayout"` suboption of GraphLayout ... [see here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8702160#8702160)

Comment: I also get Graph[<<4>>,<<3>>] with EdgeLayout in MMA9. Have you filed a note w/ tech support?

Comment: @alancalvitti I posted a question here to find out more first.  Last time I wrote to them I realised I should have waited a bit for answers here ... but yes, I will do that eventually.

Comment: There is a _little bit_ of autocompletion going on in 10.2 and friends... it keeps getting better with each iteration it seems.

Comment: @flip I haven't noticed that, but it's great news.  Can you give an example?

Comment: See [http://i.stack.imgur.com/FcPUE.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FcPUE.png) for one example. There are more that I've come across with plotting/graphics.