# Recommendations about modifying usage of built-in symbols

Tags: packages, documentation, usage-messages

In my package, I use some of the built-in *Mathematica* symbols in non-canonical ways.  Right now, I use them as `Options` or `OptionValues` to certain package symbols.  Therefore, I modified the `::usage` of the built-in symbols to include information about how those symbols are used in the package.

For example the package has a function `FoldDistribution` and I've given it an option `Integer` that can be `True` or `False`.  So I modified the `::usage` as follows:

```
Unprotect[Integer]

Integer::usage = "Integer is the head used for integer.
Integer is an option to FoldDistribution."

Protect[Integer]
```

Giving `? Integer`:

[image]

So far, things look like they're going ok, and nothing fundamentally wrong seems to be happening with how *Mathematica* operates.  **Question**: should I be worried about anything bad happening down the line?  Is it recommended not to use built-in symbols in unintended ways?  And what about changing their usage messages?

Comment: Built-ins are not bound by the same rules as top-level definitions. Do not be surprised if your modifications magically disappear at any time during a session, or are accepted in some contexts but ignored in others. Personally, I would never do this in a package.

Comment: I also think this might be error prone. But at a design level, why do you have a need to use that particular name for an option? And if it is absolutely the only name that makes sense, why not go with the string `"Integer"`?

Comment: I second the concerns of others. I would never do this. Use your own names or strings, as others have suggested. Changing properties of built-in symbols have an effect on entire system, and you can't know all the consequences. There have been multiple discussions about this here on the site, notably [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/how-can-i-speed-up-image-importing), and also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1162). You can seldom win big by changing built-ins, but it is very easy to mess things up badly.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks.  The answer by Istvan seems to disagree with your opinion.  Perhaps I should have mentioned that the *only* way I intend to use the symbols are as option names.  I don't modify their definitions.  Would this be safe?  Or would still advise against it?

Comment: QuantumDot, @Leonid It's true that the **safest** way is not to mess with builtins. But the **efficient** way is sometimes to cut corners. I often bash my head when I can't remember my periphrastic optionname which I was forced to introduced just to avoid using the otherwise straightforward name that got into the ``System` `` context with the new release... See my comments below my answer.

Comment: Related: [Why are some option values symbols, other strings?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22228/89)

Comment: @IstvánZachar I would still not do this. I do sometimes use built-ins as option names, but usually as a short-cut, and I never document that (so never really modify those symbols' global properties). And I would never do anything like that in the user-facing code. *Any* global modification you make to a built-in symbol, can have unanticipated consequences. And the more common the symbol is, the bigger are the chances to mess something up. Given other possibilities (your own names or strings), I just don't see that the the gain is worth the risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to unprotect system symbols to attach messages to them. The usual way (used throughout built-in packages) is the following way:

```
Attributes[Dot]
Message[Dot::usage]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Dot::usage = If[ValueQ[Dot::usage], Dot::usage <> "\n" <> #, #] &@ "MyFunction[..., Dot -> ...] does ...";
Message[Dot::usage]
```

**As long as you use the symbol only as an inert option name** I think this is a pretty safe method, as you do not even unprotect it so you cannot mess up its definition.

Note, that if you call the attaching code a second time, you will have a redundant message: make sure that you package this so that it is only called once. The `ValueQ` thing is only needed if you attach to a symbol that you are not sure is defined in another package, not being a system symbol.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It's good to know I don't need to unprotect the system symbol to attach messages to them.  And yes, it is true the *only* way I'm using these symbols are as option names.  So I suppose you would disagree with the comments under the original question provided I *only* use these symbols as options names?

Comment: @QuantumDot Exactly. I'm using this kind of extension since years and without any problem. I do not like to clutter the namespace with extra symbolnames, and on top of that, I do not like to use `MyIntegrate` as an option name when `Integrate` describes the best what my option does. Let's be honest, Stephen Wolfram really put a lot of thought into [naming things](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2010/10/the-poetry-of-function-naming/) and he did a quite good job. On the other hand, he really forced us to come up with convoluted names if we do not want interference.

Comment: I will accept this answer, also bearing in mind the warnings given by Leonid and Daniel as comments to the question.