# Wrapping an association with a specialization of the buildin `Set` (=) function?

Tags: programming, associations

I want to wrap some association data into a dedicated symbol (`S` by example)

```
S /: S[a_Association][k_] := a[k]
S /: Format[s_S] := 
 "Demo, here are my keys " <> ToString[Keys[First[s]]]
```

I use such approach (but AFAIK this is a common one) as I see two benefits:

1/ easy argument filtering

```
foo[S[a_Association]]:="Hello S!"
```

2/ syntaxic & looks sugar:0

```
s = S[<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>]
s["A"]
```

prints:

> ```
> "Demo, here are my keys {A, B}"
> 1
> ```

However when you have a nice syntax for `s["A"]`, you also want a nice syntax for `s["A"]=3`. This is even mandatory, as

```
s["A"]=3
```

is **misleading/bug prone**:

It does **not** change the internal association:

```
s // First
```

> <|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>

but only **binds** 3 to `s["A"]`:

```
s["A"]

3
```

So far my solution to the problem is to modify the buildin `Set` function as follows:

```
Unprotect[Set]
Set[s_Symbol[k_], v_] /; MatchQ[Hold[s] /. OwnValues[s], Hold[_S]] := 
 Block[{a = First[s]}, a[k] = v; Set[s, S[a]]]
Protect[Set]
```

Now

```
s["A"]=3
s["C"]=4
s // First
```

prints

> ```
> "Demo, here are my keys {A, B}"
> "Demo, here are my keys {A, B, C}"
> <|"A" -> 3, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 4|>
> ```

as expected.

**My question:**

Before using this in "real" developments, I would like your advices:

- is this approach ok (no side effect,...) ?
- is there a better approach/solution ?

Comment: In general you may want to set a mutation handler, see [165910](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165910/5478) and go through linked examples. And here is a broader topic that may cover what you need: [198378](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198378/5478)

Comment: Thank you @Kuba, I am going to read all this material

Comment: Redefining `Set` like this is really a last resort and is best avoided. There are alternative ways (@Kuba provided references to such).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thanks for the comment. I understand that we are very close to the "danger zone" when redefining such builtin functions. However in this very peculiar case is there a problem? (that was my motivation to ask this question here). I have started reading Kuba material, but have not digested everything yet :)

Comment: I have discussed the issues associated with `Set` overloading [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1163), so I refer you to that discussion for arguments against it. Also check out [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/recommendations-about-modifying-usage-of-built-in-symbols). None of those discussions will likely have a direct answer to your question, but the references provided by @Kuba should point you to the better direction.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin let's continue in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95159/discussion-on-question-by-picaud-vincent-wrapping-an-association-with-a-speciali).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thank you for the clarification. It's not that easy to have a correct coding level in MMA considering all these undocumented/hidden features.

Comment: @PicaudVincent Sure, was glad to help.